# How to assign an ACL for each S3 Bucket in a tuple/list using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, amazon-s3

I have a terraform file set to create a list of S3 buckets, and I was assigning acl to each bucket the old way:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
    count = length(var.s3_bucket_names)
    bucket = var.s3_bucket_names[count.index]
    acl = var.acl
    tags = var.tags
}
```

However, I want to know how to do it using `aws_s3_bucket_acl` but I can't reference the bucket because it is a tuple and not a string. I've tried a lot of things but I've got nothing so far.

This is what I want to do:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "this_acl" {
    bucket = HERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO REFERENCE A TUPLE OR LIST
    acl = var.acl
}
```

What should I do to reference a tuple since `aws_s3_bucket.this.*.id` doesn't work with a tuple/list?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution, I've created "count" for every resource:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
    count = length(var.s3_bucket_names)
    bucket = var.s3_bucket_names[count.index]
    tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "this_acl" {
    count = length(aws_s3_bucket.this)
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this[count.index].id
    acl = var.acl
}
```